# I want to catch the exception when I assign a varchar string to numeric variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**My code is as below**:

```
set serveroutput on;    
declare    
a number(3);    
alta exception;    
pragma exception_init (alta, -06550);   
begin    
a:=&numberl;    
dbms_output.put_line(a);    
exception     
when alta then    
dbms_output.put_line('this is your exception');    
end;
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What happens when you execute your code? ORA-06550 means the PL/SQL is invalid. So you are kind of saying: If this code is broken, it shall run nonetheless and tell that it's broken - which is impossible of course.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to catch ORA-06502

```
declare    
a number(3);    
alta exception;    
pragma exception_init (alta, -06502);   
begin    
a:=&numberl;    
dbms_output.put_line(a);    
exception     
when alta then    
dbms_output.put_line('this is your exception');    
end;
```

Comment: it is not working when i tried to assign a non numeric value but follwing codes are working fine according to the expectation:                              set serveroutput on;    
declare        
a number(3);       
alta exception;          
begin       
a:=to_number('&numberl');       
dbms_output.put_line(a);     
exception         
when value_error then       
dbms_output.put_line('this is your exception');        
end;

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I'm pretty sure you'd have to do `a:='&numberl';` which then does implicit conversion, to make it a runtime error rather than a compile time error which you can't catch?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trap `VALUE_ERROR`, it's a [predefined exception](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00703):

```
declare
    a number(3);
begin
    a := '&numberl';
    dbms_output.put_line(a);
exception
    when value_error then
        dbms_output.put_line('this is your exception');
end;
```

Comment: I can't test this right now, but I'm pretty sure you'd have to do `a:='&numberl';` which then does implicit conversion, to make it a runtime error rather than a compile time error which you can't catch?